# Robotframework in Pycharm. Auto-completion for variables does not work

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

i'm working with Robotframework in `Pycharm` (Windows 10) and have installed the plugin `Intellibot@SeleniumLibrary` Patched. The Auto-completion is working only for keywords, but not for variables. Does anyone have the same Problem and know how to fix it ? any suggestions?
Best regards,

Comment: I personally am using Pycharm + Intellibot for years, and don't think autocomplete on variables was ever supported by the plugin.

Comment: Why not you VSCode?, It so good support